# How to detect if string contains only latin symbols using Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, regex, ascii

I need to detect if some string contains symbols from a non latin alphabet. Numbers and special symbols like `-`, `_`, `+` are good. I need to know whether there is any non latin symbols. For example:

```
"123sdjjsf-4KSD".just_latin?
```

should return `true`.

```
"12333ыц4--sdf".just_latin?
```

should return `false`.

Comment: What about chars like éöã&$ ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by [Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_characters_in_Unicode)?

Answer (score 7):

I think that this should work for you:

```
 # encoding: UTF-8

 class String
   def just_latin?
     !!self.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-+ ]*$/)
   end
 end

 puts "123sdjjsf-4KSD".just_latin?
 puts "12333ыц4--sdf".just_latin?
```

Note that *#ascii_only?* is very close to what you want as well.

Answer (score 5):

The following regular expression will match a single letter character that is not Latin:

```
[\p{L}&&[^a-zA-Z]]
```

The `&&` syntax intersects two character classes. The first one (`\p{L}`) matches any Unicode letter. The second one `^a-zA-Z` matches any character that is **not** (`^`) a Latin one (`a-z` or `A-Z`). I.e. the whole character class matches any letter that is not a Latin one.

[See it working on Rubular.](http://www.rubular.com/r/IIzEVnUtbf)

So if you use this regular expression inside `just_latin?` and return `true` if no match is found, it should work just like you want it to.

I tried with the Unicode property `\p{Latin}` for the second character class before, but that is not entirely reliable, since `\p{Latin}` includes for instance the Icelandic characters `þ`, `æ`, `ð`.

Answer (score 1):

There you go, just match those characteres and you are done (`a-z` means characteres from `a` to `z`): `^[a-zA-Z_\-+]+$`

Comment: Well, he said that those letters plus those symbols. And about anchors, if he need it on the whole string, I don't think they are needed.

Comment: The second input string will be matched by your pattern. Once at `12333` and once at `4--sdf`. That's why you need anchors to prevent the match. About the other characters. He said "specials symbols like...", but I guess that's disputable. Sure, if the OP has a list of specific characters he wants to allow, your pattern (with anchors) is the way to go.