# How can you limit ïnput to English characters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a lot of submissions to my publicly editable site in different languages, but would like to limit it to just English characters. Is there any simple way to do this? Should I just do a validation with a regex limiting characters, or are there any common issues with that method?

Note: The text will not contain HTML or any other markup. It should just be plain text, maybe with common characters like dashes, dots, etc.

Comment: It depends on what language you want to prevent. If they are latin based languages, then forget it. About a dozen or more languages use the same letterset, and even more use the same letter subset. Not to mention English itself has accents, such as naïve.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't mind restricting words like naïve. But I'm trying to reduce submissions in Arabic, various Cyrillic alphabets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`validates :comment, format: { with: [a-zA-Z0-9\s]+, on: :create }` - or other action

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your problem maybe spam, so there are better solutions you can use. If this is true, see the end of this answer for details.

I commented that depends on which languages you want to block. A dozen or more languages use a latin charset, and even more use a latin charset subset. English uses accents too, such as the word naïve. So I do not recommend you try and do this.

If you must, and you want to block none-latin characters, you can write a custom validator.

```
class LatinCharsetValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  # Regex taken from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13671443/276959
  LATIN_CHARSET_REGEX = /[\p{L}&&[^a-zA-Z]]/

  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    object.errors.add(attribute) if value =~ LATIN_CHARSET_REGEX
  end
end
```

You can then call this validator in your model as such:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :comment, latin_charset: true
end
```

This assumes that your users are legitimately trying to comment. If not, you can use the regex to skip the comment creation without providing feedback.

I believe this is a bad idea, though. You can't control what people end up writing or pasting in the text area, and you might end up blocking legitimate comments. What if someone wants to include a foreign word while trying to explain it? It's better to politely ask your users to only comment in English.

If your problem is spam, however, you are better off implementing a [honeypot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_(computing)) or some other type of spam protection.